# C++ struct mapped onto peripheral registers

Tags: c++, memory, struct, volatile, bit-fields

Let's say I have following code in C++ running on a [Zynq-7000 SoC](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds190-Zynq-7000-Overview.pdf)

```
  struct ControlReg
  {
    uint32_t reset_bit : 1;
  };

  struct ConfigReg
  {
    uint32_t even_channel_value : 16;
    uint32_t odd_channel_value : 16;
  };

  struct PeripheralRegs
  {
    volatile ControlReg control_reg;
    volatile uint32_t status_reg_01[2];
    volatile uint32_t status_reg_02[2];
    volatile ConfigReg config_reg_01[8];
    volatile ConfigReg config_reg_02[8];
    volatile uint32_t status_reg_03[2];
  };

  PeripheralRegs *regs;
  regs = new (reinterpret_cast<void *>(0x43C20000)) PeripheralRegs;

  uint16_t value = 6573;

  regs->config_reg_01[0].odd_channel_value = value;
  regs->config_reg_01[0].even_channel_value = value;
```

I have stepped through this code in debugger and I have found that the `config_reg_01[0]`
contains all zeros despite the attempt to write the `6573` value into it. Can anybody tell me why this behavior occurs? It is strange for me that in case I write some value into the `status_reg_01[0]` I see this value at the appropriate address in the "memory monitor" in the debugger.

**EDIT**:

I have partially found the reason why this behavior occurs. It is somehow related to the code optimization. This conclusion is based on the observation that the problem vanished in case I switched the code optimization level from O2 to O0 in the ARM v7 g++ compiler settings. Second observation which I have is that in case I use code optimization level O2 and made following modifications:

```
  struct ControlReg
  {
    volatile uint32_t reset_bit : 1;
  };

  struct ConfigReg
  {
    volatile uint32_t even_channel_value : 16;
    volatile uint32_t odd_channel_value : 16;
  };
```

the same correct behavior occurs as in the case with optimization level O0.
Can anybody explain to me why the `volatile` keyword applied onto the bitfields items has such huge impact in relation to the code optimization.

Comment: Seems like the HW is preventing you from writing into config_reg_01 register. Perhaps there is another register that allows you to unlock that register.

Comment: Make sure the relevant clock is enabled. For details look at the chips reference manual.

Comment: @doron do you think that the problem could be caused by wrong mapping of the 'PeripheralRegs' structure onto memory? Is there any method how to rule out this hypothesis?

Comment: Without the docs, I have no idea

Answer (score 1):

From the *[Zynq-7000](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug585-Zynq-7000-TRM.pdf)* reference manual, the address `0x43C20000` is in the *Programmable Logic* address area of the device ("*General Purpose Port #0*" : 4000_0000 to 7FFF_FFFF).  The behaviour of that location will depend (presumably - I am not familiar with the part) on the logic implemented (if any).

Moreover it is possible to power down the Programmable Logic (PL) block in which case it will do nothing (an loose its configuration).

So as it stands it is not possible to say what should happen in this example, but what is happening is clearly plausible.  Unless and until you have powered up the PL and configured it accessing that address region makes no little sense.

Also there appear to be TrustZone security features on the device that may lock you out of access to specific regions, not to mention the ARM-A9's MMU that may remap physical addresses to virtual ones or prevent access to a region entirely.

The code you reference is plausible, and for programmable logic probably useful; but the address and register names need to relate to the actual hardware or programmable logic configuration in effect.

Answer (score 0):

In RAM if you set a bit and read it back, you will get the value you set. Peripherals do not always behave like this. This is why peripheral memory must be declared volatile since no assumptions about RAM-like behaviour can be made.

A typical example is acknowledging an interrupt. You acknowledge the interrupt by setting the interrupt status bit to 1. This will clear the interrupt so when you subsequently read the interrupt status you will typically get back as zero.

Successive reads may also get different value.

Comment: thank you for your reaction. As far as I understand you think that it could be a normal behavior of my platform. I have edited my question as far as the behavior of the other registers.